# find mongoose matching items inside an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I have a mongoose schema with an array of objects...
Im trying to get only matching `userID` in the array, however the array return all the users if there is even one match.
I have the following on node js

```
app.get("/myanswers/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const q = await posts.find(
      { "postAnswer.userID": req.params.id },
      "postAnswer.answer postAnswer._id postAnswer.user postAnswer.userID"
    );
    res.json(q);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
});
```

and i get this result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6074f2648e9f41497438b37a",
        "postAnswer": [
            {
                "_id": "6074f3858e9f41497438b37b",
                "userID": "60579272980cb93ea8a91140",
                "user": "admin",
                "answer": "Kakashi ‍"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6074f4768e9f41497438b37c",
        "postAnswer": [
            {
                "_id": "6074f5338e9f41497438b37e",
                "userID": "6074f4f98e9f41497438b37d",
                "user": "barrym",
                "answer": "here's the correct sequence. table, add row table headers close row. add row add table data close row close table."
            },
            {
                "_id": "6074f5808e9f41497438b37f",
                "userID": "60579272980cb93ea8a91140",
                "user": "admin",
                "answer": "with TH and TD!"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i only want exact match so user `barrym` shouldn't appear

Answer (score 2):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/3BV58F3GiS4

Use [$ (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

Note:- **limits the contents of an  to return the first element**

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  to return the first element that matches the query condition on the array.

```
db.collection.find(
 { "postAnswer.userID": "6074f4f98e9f41497438b37d"},
 { "postAnswer.$": 1}
)
```

Comment: This only limits results.. not what I need. I need matching results only with `postAnswer.userID`

Comment: @KashifAli Did you check the demo? What is the expected output?